# Going through the stack

Tags: c, winapi, x86, stack, x86-64

I made a simple function to iterate through the whole stack and print out contents of each entry in there.

```
void ListStack()
{
    NT_TIB* tib = (NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb();

    for (void* address = tib->StackBase; address > tib->StackLimit; address = (char*)address - sizeof(void*))
    {
        void* pointsTo = *((void**)address);

        printf("address=%p, points to=%p\n", address, pointsTo);
    }
}
```

On x86, this works fine. However, on x64, it gives me read access violation.
What's wrong with this?

Comment: What information did you gather running the code under a debugger? Specifically, which expression/statement failed with an access violation?

Comment: @IInspectable `void* pointsTo = *((void**)address);` 
It's the first iteration of the loop when it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are dereferencing `tib->StackBase`.

The stack region is greater than or equal to `tib->StackLimit` and *less than* `tib->StackBase`.  It is very likely that the page that page containing `tib->StackBase` will not be mapped into memory.

So just change your for loop to look like this:

```
for (void* address = (char*)tib->StackBase - sizeof(void*);
           address >= tib->StackLimit;
           address = (char*)address - sizeof(void*))
```